# Call variable js in a url

Tags: javascript, html, url

I want to retrieve variables from the javascript code and pass them as a parameter of a url in the html code:

here the javascript code

```js
function fparsexml() {

  var param = '{"id":"3753612"}';
  var fun4 = "getJsonradio";
  var radio = false;
  var parser, xmlDoc;
  var radio1;


  //fonction getJsonradio
  $.post("http://192.168.20.1:1111/newone/client.php", {
    fun: fun4,
    param: param
  }, function(result) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(result, "text/xml");
    //var id_radio=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("id").length;
    var id_radio = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name");

    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      alert((id_radio[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue));
      //document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = id_radio[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      var radios = id_radio[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

      if (i == 4) {
        var rad = true;
      }

    }
    radio1 = radios

  })
```

here the HTML Code

```html
<a href="afiichage.php?radio=radio1">ENVOYER</a>
```

Comment: And what is the issue you are facing with your current code?

Comment: what the problem in that? you can simply write you HTML Link into response of your post or ajax or whatever function you are calling...

Comment: It shows me nothing in the  distination page it seems that the variable radio1 is empty

Comment: her my code in disination page                                                             <?php

if (isset($_GET['radio1'])) 
{
 echo 'Bonjour ' . $_GET['radio1'] ;
}
else 
{
 echo 'Il faut renseigner rario !';
}
 ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the anchor tag in your Javascript and modify the `href` attribute.

Also resolved your syntax errors, provide closing brace to your function.

And declare `radios` outside, otherwise there will be a scope issue when you use it in `radio1 = radios;`

```js
<script>

  function fparsexml() {

    var param = '{"id":"3753612"}';
    var fun4 = "getJsonradio";
    var radio = false;
    var parser, xmlDoc;
    var radio1, radios;


    //fonction getJsonradio
    $.post("http://192.168.20.1:1111/newone/client.php", {
        fun: fun4,
        param: param
    }, function(result) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(result, "text/xml");
        //var id_radio=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("id").length;
        var id_radio = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name");

        for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            alert((id_radio[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue));
            //document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = id_radio[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            radios = id_radio[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

            if (i == 4) {
                var rad = true;
            }

        }
        radio1 = radios;
        var elem = document.getElementById("atag");
        var href = elem.getAttribute("href");
        elem.setAttribute("href", href + "?radio=" + radio1);
    });

}

</script>
```

```html
<a id="atag" href="afiichage.php>ENVOYER</a>
```

Comment: thank you nashcheez but it's return me error in elem.setAttribute("href", href + "?radio=" + radio1);

Answer (score 0):

What url are you looking for?

```
var cuurentURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;
```

In the anchor

```
document.getElementById("myAnchor").href = "http://www.foobar.com/";
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to pass javascript variables as parameters in the html code

Comment: You want to hard Code the variables in html.. Those are often  called templates. Libraries like handlebars are designed to handle that for you.